# autocomplete UI com PHP não aceita acentos

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

Colegas.

Estou usando o autocomplete UI para uma aplicação, funciona bem até o momento em que a palavra tem acentos. O banco está configurado como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que estou usando é:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtBuscar" name="BuscarProduto" placeholder="Buscar Produto">
<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Autocomplete -->
<script>
  $( function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#txtBuscar" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax( {
          url: "buscar.php",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            term: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
                      response( data );
            //response( data );

          }
        } );
      },
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );
      }
    } );
  } );
  </script>
```

O meu PHP está dessa forma:

```
...
$nomeProduto = $_GET["term"];
$sqlBuscar = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE NomeProdutos LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$nomeProduto)."%';");
  $trazer = array();
  while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlBuscar)){
        $trazer[] = $mostrar["NomeProdutos"];
  }
echo json_encode($trazer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente colocar a seguinte função (utf8_encode):

```
$nomeProduto = $_GET["term"];
$sqlBuscar = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE NomeProdutos LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$nomeProduto)."%';");
  $trazer = array();
  while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlBuscar)){
        $trazer[] = utf8_encode($mostrar["NomeProdutos"]); //funcao aqui
  }
echo json_encode($trazer);
```

Comment: Bingo Deyvid. Funcionou. Não me atentei a essa função nativa. Obrigado.